# ドメインでサイトが開けません。

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu

[設置した掲示板](https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan)
環境はubuntuです。上の掲示板を設置して、ドメインのほうも設置しました。
（仮にIPは123.45.6.789として、上の掲示板はポートは5000です。）
設置したドメインにアクセスしたら、"Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"と表示されました。そのあとにapache2が動いていると思ったので、/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf の所に

```
ProxyPass / http://123.45.6.789:5000
ProxyPassReverse / http://123.45.6.789:5000
```

と追記しました。
そしたら、サイトにアクセスできました。しかし、ここから違うところにアクセスしたら以下のように表示されました。どうすれば直りますか？

> Proxy Error
>   The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /sample/.
>   Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 123.45.6.789:5000sample
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at domain Port 443

あと、このサイトをEncryptを使って暗号化しました。
関係のあるファイルを一応載せておきます

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ProxyPass / http://IP:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://IP:5000/
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain IP:5000 domain
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ProxyPass / http://domain:5000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://domain:5000
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain IP:5000 domain

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/144789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 123.45.6.789:5000sample

ProxyPass で設定したURLのマッピングに問題があり、「123.45.6.789:5000sample」というサーバーに接続しようとして 存在しないのでエラーになっています。

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf` の当該部分の最後に `/` を付け加えてみてください。

```
    ProxyPass / http://domain:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://domain:5000/
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！開けました。しかし、別の問題が発生しました。スレッドを作ろうとしたら’Error : mongodb exception : no variable id in line 24’と表示され、エラーが発生しました。どうすればいいですか？

Comment: @user 新しく出たエラーメッセージとやらでweb検索すると、あなたが別サイトで質問したページがヒットします。 - https://teratail.com/questions/133702 ベストアンサーを選ばれているなら解決済みではないのですか？いずれにせよ、この質問(ドメイン名でアクセスできない)とは内容が異なるので、この場で続けず別質問を開くなどしてください。

Comment: そうですね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: ソースを見ると `out_status_text = 'mongodb exception : no variable ''id'' in line 23'; -- joke` とありますので、気にしなくて良いエラーじゃないでしょうか。よくわかりませんが、初回はデータがないので必ずエラーになるとかそういうオチではないかと想像します。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。